# Defining a custom list of files in pom.xml

Tags: xml, maven, pom.xml, nexus

I have a pom.xml that acts as a root POM for a hierarchy of child pom, each of which are responsible for deploying it's own corresponding binary artifacts.

I originally wanted to have the root POM store a list of these child pom so that I can do some pre-/post-processing with the child POMs. Here's an example of what the room pom.xml looked like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>company.group1.project1</groupId>
<artifactId>assets</artifactId>
<version>0.4.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>company.shared</groupId>
    <artifactId>repo-info-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

<deployArtifacts exportType="bin" srcType="txt">
    <artifacts>
        <artifact>
            <artifactId>assetA</artifactId>
            <groupId>company.group1.project1.assets</groupId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
            <fileFolder>./assetA/</fileFolder>
        </artifact>
        <artifact>
            <artifactId>assetB</artifactId>
            <groupId>company.group1.project1.assets</groupId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
            <fileFolder>./anotherFolder/assetB</fileFolder>
        </artifact>
            <artifact>
            <artifactId>assetC</artifactId>
            <groupId>company.group1.project1.assets</groupId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
            <fileFolder>./yet/another/folder/assetC</fileFolder>
        </artifact>
    </artifacts>
</deployArtifacts>

</project>
```

Granted, POM has its own XSD which rejects custom tags and will give me a "Malformed POM" error if I attempt to use it.

For alternatives I have been looking into:

1. The  tag won't allow me to add directory information unless it's the  for when  is system, which I don't think I should use, since I do wish to have the root POM be able to also reference the artifacts from the repository eventually.
2. The  list only references the artifacts within the local project, and doesn't appear to allow me to attach information such as groupID or version number.
3. As a last resort, I was thinking of removing the  list from the root pom.xml, move it to another xml, and have the root pom.xml attatch this new xml as another artifact with the build-helper-maven plugin.

This is my first time setting up and configuring Maven, so I'm wondering what other viable options are there. Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation which seem to match your requirements. It'll make it possible to execute Maven from the root and build/deploy all its children.